# install virtualbox 4.3 on ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

**Hey there,**

i updated my ubuntu to 15.10 and suddenly my virtualbox isnt working anymore.
So i tried to install just an older version, that didnt work and i tried to downgrade my virtual box,that also didnt work.

Is there any option to install virtual box version 4.3(4.0,4.1,4.2 are possible too) on ubuntu 15.10 or any other solutions?

I googled a lot and tried alot but no solution till now.
Would be nice if someone can help me here :)

greetings!

Comment: Maybe try asking on http://askubuntu.com/ instead?

Answer (score 0):

was facing same issue of VM's crashing (Virtual Box) after upgrading to 15.10 Wily. They have added at new version Ubuntu 15.10 ("Wily") i386 | AMD64 at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/691559/virtualbox-4-x-on-ubuntu-15-10/691565?noredirect=1#comment1009905_691565

thnx anyway =)